# How to match a character in a string and lookup value from a table in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to check for a character in a string and if it matches I want to look up the value of that character from a table.
e.g., I want to check a character F (A94) in the string HPCS (B63), if TRUE then the value 2 (B94) from the table (A34:B105) should be the outcome (at the position B65). If FALSE the value should be 0.
Does anybody know how to do that in excel?

[image: The excel file looks like this.]

Comment: How would `S` and `XS` behave if the string consists `XS`?

Comment: Hi P.B, this is not a problem cause in my data S and XS are not occurring simultaneously.

Comment: No, but `XS` in `B63` would return a value for both `XS` and `S`. If that's not a problem, then Harun's formula is alright.

Comment: No, that is not a problem. Harun's formula worked just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try to below formula. But **P.B** raise a good point in comment. You need to clarify that.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,$B$1)),INDEX($F$4:$F$14,MATCH(A3,$E$4:$E$14,0)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know it helps.